# Why is my parent function not rounding but when I call it in another function, it gets rounded?

Tags: python

```
import math
class Shape(object):
    def __init__(self,base,side,theta=90):
        self.base=base
        self.side=side
        self.theta=theta

    def area(self):
        return float(self.base*self.side*math.sin(math.radians(self.theta)))

    def __str__(self):    
        return ('I am a %s with area of %d' %
    (self.__class__.__name__,(float(self.area()))))
```

When I call `area()` I get an unrounded number (ie. 73.56299996178102), but when I call the `str` it returns `73`

Comment: See above ^^^^^

Answer (score 4):

Because of the format specifier you're using:

```
In [1]: '%d' % 3.14
Out[1]: '3'
```

`%d` (the C-style string formatter for `int`) will truncate any float if you pass it that. Instead, the correct format specifier string to use would be `%f`:

```
In [2]: '%f' % 3.14
Out[2]: '3.140000'
```

However, I'd recommend using `str.format` instead, so you don't have to worry about what format specifier to use.

```
def __str__(self):
    return 'I am a {} with area of {}'.format(self.__class__.__name__, self.area())
```

`str.format` also gives you better control over display for floating point numbers:

```
In [3]: '{:.2f}'.format(3.1415)
Out[3]: '3.14'
```

Read more about the format functions at [PyFormat.info](https://pyformat.info).